# Newbie Drupal-8 styling. How do I change font colour?

Tags: css, drupal-8

So I'm trying to help migrate my running clubs website from Drupal-7 to Drupal-8.

Some of the content uses 'font Color' to (not suprisingly) change the font colour.
In Drupal-8 this does not seem to work, the font stays black.

(I'll admit I don't really understand CSS and HTML very well)

```
<strong><font Color=" #9933ff">My Test</Strong>
```

Is this something I need to change in:

color.css
style.css

in my custom theme ? Or can I make a change in the expression above?

Mark

Comment: You would want to do something like <strong style="color: #9933ff;">My Test</strong> if you wanted the style to be inline

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to press the 'source' button first in the toolbar in the drupal editor.